# I have built a tube amp but the voltage drop doesn't work as expected

Tags: voltage

The original schematic had 180 V before the diode rectifier. Multiplied with 1.4 that makes 252 V. I could only get a transformer with 200 V, so I added a voltage drop after the rectifier.

I calculated to get from (measured) 286 V to 252 V(0,085 A) by using a 0,4kOhm (3 *1,2kOhm parallel) resistor, but the measured result after the voltage drop is 278 V. I don't understand why this value is different than calculated. Can someone help me understand the difference in the measured vs calculated values.

[image]

Comment: it's `180 V`, not 180volt ... and always put spaces between words ... you would not write eightyvolt

Comment: How sure are you the current wat 85 mA while you were measuring the drop?

Comment: I got the 85mA from the datasheet of the transformer. So I'm not sure in real world its also the same value

Comment: @Eternal_Sunshine Currents listed in transformer datasheets are usually going to be *maximum allowed currents*, not a constant current. The current depends on your circuitry.

Comment: Except the voltage drop its like the schematics

Comment: I changed it to V

Comment: You will need to know how much current your circuit is drawing to determine how much voltage is dropped by a series resistor.  That will always be load-dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dropping 8 V over 400\$\Omega\$ which means the amp is drawing 20 mA. This is going to be the idle current, when you put in a signal it's going to draw more.

If you figure on dropping 34 V at idle that will take a 1700\$\Omega\$ resistor. The thing then is that when the amp draws more current the voltage will drop more. Let's say you hook up a guitar and play loud, maybe the draw is now 50 mA, and the drop would be 85 V. This variation of the supply voltage is going to affect the sound of the amp. Some people like a bit of 'softness' in their amps because this is one of the things that happens with tube rectifiers, the voltage sags a bit on volume peaks.

You probably don't need to get the voltage down to exactly what it was in the original, the tubes should probably handle some extra voltage. So you might try some different resistance values between the 400\$\Omega\$ up to the 1700\$\Omega\$ to see how it sounds with different amounts of voltage sag. You could get some idea of how much current is drawn at higher volume by measuring the drop with some signal into the amp.

If you want the voltage to remain relatively constant you would need to use some type of regulator, or a load that will draw enough current to keep the voltage drop within a narrower range.

Comment: As a regulator, you *may* be able to get something to work with an LM317, which only cares about the difference between its input and output voltages (and not the magnitude of those voltages relative to ground), but be sure you do the thermal calculations! Good regulation of a voltage this high is not trivial to do efficiently.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Right now the amps works fine except with very low gain it is already distorting a little bit. Is that maybe because of the higher B+ voltage?

Comment: @Eternal_Sunshine Hard to say, generally tube amps are pretty forgiving of the supply voltage.  The 12AX7A  is rated at a plate voltage of 330V max, the 12AU7A I think is 300V, so you should be okay there. You'd probably have to go through it with a scope (cautiously) to see which stage(s) are distorting and then figure out why.

Comment: The output stage looks like class A in which case the current does not change with increased output.

Comment: @KevinWhite Could be. I'm used to seeing high power push-pull outputs that are class AB but this is low power so class A is an option. In that case using something in the 1700 ohm range should work. 2 W or higher resistor, I'd probably go with 4 W.